# Window function helper in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

In Postgres, it is possible to transform this:

```sql
select
  stuff,
  lag(dt) over (order by something, something else, dt) as first_lag,
  lag(hello) over (order by something, something else, dt) as second_lag
from table
```

Into that:

```sql
select
  stuff,
  lag(dt) over w as first_lag,
  lag(hello) over w as second_lag
from table
window w as (order by something, something else, dt)
```

In order to avoid repeating the same `window` statement over and over (my real-world scenario is I'd repeat it at least five to ten times within `case when ... then` statements etc).

I haven't noticed such capability in Presto's documentation, and trying the same as above just doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve such repetition in Presto, even if it is with a different syntax?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to simplify this syntax in PrestoDB.

Comment: This is currently not supported by Presto. I filed an issue to track this improvement: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/651